# What order does excel follow for "Refresh All"

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have been searching around ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel%20order%20of%20refresh%20all), [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20order%20does%20excel%20refresh%20all), [3](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20order%20of%20refresh%20all), etc.) looking to find what algorithm/process excel (any version, preferably 2013 or 2016) has to determine what order things get refreshed when you `Refresh All`. Is it order of worksheets, date last modified, date last created, name of worksheets, etc.

Basically, (it's shoddy and not smart - I know and am fixing) I have a pivot table that references a range containing another pivot table that references a table and I have to do `Refresh All` twice because I think the last pivot table is updating before the first pivot table, when it should update after.

I have found plenty of code to control the order (go to any of the websites that show up in [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20order%20does%20excel%20refresh%20all) and [3](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20order%20of%20refresh%20all) above), but nothing about what the actual, native order is. I have a simple workbook (maybe not so simple given the above circumstances) that I do not want to add any `vba` to. If I can restructure something in my workbook to accommodate how excel operates normally that is just fine.

While probably half my problem is that I have a pivot table referencing another pivot table (which is something I am fixing), I have found people with more legitimate `Refresh All` problems (for OLAP or database connections, etc.). I have not found the order in which excel "refreshes all" in my research and [I think](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) this is something that should be documented in order to improve excel usage overall.

Comment: What do you mean by the "table that references a table" in your statement "pivot table that references *a table that references a table*"

Comment: @jeffreyweir, tks, I updated the question.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? Where is your data coming from? OLAP and ranges? What kind of data sources do you have? Are you just talking about PivotTables, or are you using PowerQuery or something else too?

Comment: @jeffreyweir the original source of the data is from a table in one of the worksheets. The first pivot table is in another worksheet and the second pivot table is in a third worksheet. I am using Excel 2016. Do the rules on `Refresh All` vary based on the circumstances?

Comment: No, they don't vary by model. I ask version so I can see if you have a version that ships with the DataModel. PivotTables based on the datamodel allow you to do the type of thing that you are currently using pivots based on pivots to do.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a PivotTable based on a PivotTable? i.e. what kind of summarizations are you wanting to do on the first PivotTable's output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm *pretty* sure that Excel simply iterates through the underlying PivotCaches that the PivotTables are based on by index number. But I also suspect that it turns calculation off while it does it, meaning that if you have a PivotTable based on a PivotTable it will not get refreshed unless you click the RefreshAll button twice.